# remove duplicates based on a value in a row

Tags: unix, awk

I have a file with below contents

```
1,2,3,2
2,3,2,3
2,1,2
2,4,2,3,1
```

I have to remove duplicates(need one appearance in my O/P)  based on a row and my o/p should be

```
1,2,3
2,3
2,1
2,4,3,1
```

Let me know if there is any way to perform the same using awk or some other commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will be alot easier with `perl`:

```
perl -F, -lane'my %seen; print join ",", grep { !$seen{$_}++ } @F' file
1,2,3
2,3
2,1
2,4,3,1
```

We split the line on `,` and create an array `@F`. We use a hash `%seen` to populate the numbers from array grep the numbers which are unique.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for generic or any specific solutions. You can use `Python`

Example:

```
x = ["line1","line2","line3","line2","line1"]
y= list(set(x))
print (y)

output:
line3","line2","line1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, '{s=""; delete a;
         for(x=1;x<=NF;x++){if(!($x in a))s=s sprintf("%s,",$x);a[$x]}
         sub(/,$/,"",s);print s}' file
1,2,3
2,3
2,1
2,4,3,1
```

Comment: i ran the awk command.it gave me below error,not sure whether there is any problem with my awk version                                
> for(x=1;x<=NF;x++){if(!($x in a))s=s sprintf("%s,",$x);a[$x]}
> sub(/,$/,"",s);print s}' a.dat
 Syntax Error The source line is 1.
 The error context is
                {s=""; delete >>>  a; <<<
 awk: 0602-502 The statement cannot be correctly parsed. The source line is 1.

Comment: @user2737481 tested with gnu awk.

Answer (score 0):

This is was interesting. 
This is how I done:

```
awk '{
  len=split($0,a,","); 
  for(i=1; i<=len; i++){ 
    prt = 1;
    for(j=i-1; j>0; j--){ 
      if (a[i]==a[j]){
        prt = 0;
        continue; 
      }
    }
    if (prt ==   1){
      printf a[i]",";
    }
  }
}' | sed 's/,$//'
```